# Why do I have a shape behind my image in a container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I tried to make a card with round corners, but when I did so, the card below the image was bigger than the image. Below is my code and a screenshot of a part of my app to show you my problem. I hope you can see on the screenshot that next to the image, in the corners is a shape.

```
Card(
                child: InkWell(
                  splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BodyConstruction(),
                    ));
                  },
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                    child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
                  )
                ),
              ),
```

[image: the screenshot of my card]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the shape of your Card. Also, you can simplify your borderRadius:

```
Card(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
      ),
      child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
            onTap: () {
               Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BodyConstruction(),
                ));
            },
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Your result will be the following:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  ),

There are several shape attributes that you can play around with. Here is the flutter doc for that :

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ShapeBorder-class.html

The code you have only applies to the image and not the card itself. Hope that helps.